# How to Vlookup in excel with 2 conditions

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm evaluating my portfolio, and I make a record of it in some form like this:

[image: excel]

I wish to get the profit% of those stocks, from either;

1. Stocks with sold: (Price at SELL/Price at BUY)-1
2. Stocks not sold: (Current Price/Price at BUY)-1

For 1), I was thinking of getting the Last Price (Col E) of Stock A by using VLOOKUP conditioning with 'Stock A' of Col B and a 'SELL' of Col C (then obviously using the VLOOKUP again with 'SELL' condition changed to 'BUY').

Is there a way to look up a value with two conditions? Any other suggestions (using a touch of VBA for eg) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `Stock A` alwiys only have 1 line for `BUY` and one line for `SELL` or can there be more (like 2 `BUY`s for `Stock A`) and what shoult happen then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `VLOOKUP` is, in effect, a special form of `INDEX MATCH` (or `XLOOKUP`, from Office365 onwards).  In other words, `VLOOKUP("Value", A:C, 3, FALSE)` is the same as `INDEX(C:C, MATCH("Value", A:A, 0))`, and `VLOOKUP("Value", A:C, 3, TRUE)` is the same as `INDEX(C:C, MATCH("Value", A:A, 1))`

Then, to create a `VLOOKUP` equivalent that checks multiple columns, we need to create a `MATCH` function to do the same.  Fortunately, this is possibly using Array Calculations.

Essentially, we replace the second argument of the `MATCH` (the list of values to look for) with a formula which creates an Array based on our Conditions, and we Search the list for where the conditions are True.  For example, if our Conditions are `Column B = "Stock A"` and `Column C = "BUY"`, then our Array Calculation is `(B:B="Stock A")*(C:C="Buy")`, and our `MATCH` looks like this:

```
MATCH(1, (B:B="Stock A")*(C:C="BUY"), 0)
```

(At a Boolean or Bitwise level, `*` is the same as `AND`: `TRUE*TRUE=TRUE`, `FALSE*FALSE=FALSE`, `TRUE*FALSE=FALSE`)

Rather than using Entire Columns (which are Slow), it is often best to limit the number of rows.  You can either do this manually:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$E$5, MATCH(1, ($B$1:$B$5="Stock A")*($C$1:$C$5="BUY"), 0))
```

Or you can do it dynamically with `INDEX` and `COUNTA`:

```
=INDEX($E$1:INDEX($E:$E, COUNTA($A:$A)), MATCH(1, ($B$1:INDEX($B:$B, COUNTA($A:$A)), ="Stock A")*($C$1:INDEX($C:$C, COUNTA($A:$A)), ="BUY"), 0))
```

Final note: the `MATCH` function will start at the *top* of the list, and work down until the first match.  If these are in Date Order, and you want to find the *last* match, then Office356 users have [the `XMATCH` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312) available, which has an extra argument used to decide if the search is First-to-Last (`XMATCH(.., .., .., 1)`), Last-to-First (`XMATCH(.., .., .., -1)`), Ascending Binary Search (`XMATCH(.., .., .., 2)`), or Descending Binary Search (`XMATCH(.., .., .., -2)`)

Otherwise, you may have to use `SUMPRODUCT` to get the `MAX` date that matches your criteria, and include that in your `MATCH` conditions (`SUMPRODUCT(MAX(A:A*(B:B="Stock A")*(C:C="BUY"))`)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to look up a value with two conditions?

There is a very simple solution - you can concatenate (using `&`) the two columns holding conditions for your search into one and then base your `VLOOKUP` search on that column. Remember to put this concatenated column at beginning of your table.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that the combination `Stock A - BUY` and `Stock A - SELL` occur only once like in

[image]

and **never** twice like in

[image]

Then you can use the `SUMIFS` function to "lookup" the value. Because the sum of only one value will always be the value itself:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,"Stock A",C:C,"BUY")/SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,"Stock A",C:C,"SELL") -1
```

To be sure there is only one entry per combination you can use the `COUNTIFS` to check it and return a warning in case of multiple entries (which would result in a false value):

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(B:B,"Stock A",C:C,"BUY")=1,COUNTIFS(B:B,"Stock A",C:C,"SELL")=1), SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,"Stock A",C:C,"BUY")/SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,"Stock A",C:C,"SELL") -1,"multiple entries found")
```